# Button won't work after returning form with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm displaying a form via **ajax** based on some drop downs menus. User can can select the **class** on one dropdown and **subject** on another, which in turn returns a list of students in that class.

This is formated in a form like manner that allows user to enter scores of subjects that a student have acquire. This is how the form looks after user have selected their preferences:
[image]

I want when the save button is click and after user have enter the score, it should be send to the database. **The problem is:** since I'm returning the records via **ajax** whenever I click the button nothing happens. For basic testing I tried to display a javascript alert and log a message to the console when the button is click, but nothing happens when I tried.

This is how my code looks: (script)

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#subject_id').on('change', function(){
      var subject_id = $('#subject_id').val();
      var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
      var term = $('#term').val();

    if (subject_id != '' || class_id != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url:"includes/ajax/read_student_score_form.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{"subject":subject_id, "class":class_id, "term":term},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
          $("#result").html(data);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#result").html('');

    }   
}); 

$('#class_id').on('change', function(){
    var subject_id = $('#subject_id').val();
    var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
    var term = $('#term').val();

    if (subject_id != '' || class_id != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url:"includes/ajax/read_student_score_form.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{"subject":subject_id, "class":class_id, "term":term},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
          $("#result").html(data);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#result").html('');
    }   
});

$('#term').on('change', function() {
  /* Act on the event */
    var subject_id = $('#subject_id').val();
    var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
    var term = $('#term').val();

    if (subject_id != '' || class_id != '') {
        $.ajax({
          url:"includes/ajax/read_student_score_form.php",
          method:"post",
          data:{"subject":subject_id, "class":class_id, "term":term},
          dataType:"text",
          success:function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
          }
        });
    } else {
      $("#result").html('');
    }   
}); 


// testing is done down here
$(document).on('submit', '#st_score_form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // this is where I'm testing if the button is working
    alert("Button click");
    console.log("Button click");

});
});
</script>
```

This is the file that is returning the form(includes/ajax/read_student_score_form.php)

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    # code...
    $output .= '<h4 align="center">Periodic Report</h4>';
    $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">

                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" colspan="1">Subject</th>
                            <td colspan="5">'.$subject["subject_name"].'</td>

                            <th scope="row">Class</th>
                            <td>'.$class['class_name'].'</td>

                            <th scope="row">Period</th>
                            <td>'.$period.'</td>
                        </tr>';
        $output .= '</table>';
        $output .= '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Student</th>
                                <th>Score</th>
                                <th>Operations</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>';
            $output .= '<tbody>';
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    # code...
                    $output .= '<form action="#" method="post" id="st_score_form">';
                        // unseen post values that will be send
                        $output .= '<tr style="display: none;">';
                            $output .= '<td><input type="text" name="student_id" value="'.$row['student_id'].'"></td>';
                            $output .= '<td><input type="text" name="subject_id" value="'.$subject_id.'"></td>';
                            $output .= '<td><input type="text" name="class_id" value="'.$class_id.'"></td>';
                            $output .= '<td><input type="text" name="term" value="'.$term.'"></td>';
                        $output .= '</tr>';
                        // -- end of unseen post values

                        $output .= '<tr>';
                            $output .= '<td>'.$row["first_name"]." ".substr($row["middle_name"], 0, 1).". ".$row["surname"].'</td>';
                            $output .= '<td><input type="number" min="59" max="100"  name="score" class="form-control"></td>';
                            $output .= '<div class="form-group">';
                            $output .= '<td><input type="submit" name="savebtn" id="savebtn" value="Save" class="btn btn-info form-control"></td>';
                            $output .= '</div>';

                        $output .= '</tr>';
                    $output .= '</form>';
                }
            $output .= '</tbody>';
        $output .= '</table>';
    $output .= '</div>';            
    echo $output;
} else {
    echo "Data not found";
}
```

I'm open to feed backs and suggestions on ways I can make this work. Thanks!!!

Comment: At your `$(document).ready` you have a syntax error, is that from copying the code or an error you missed? There's an extra `});`

Comment: @Lixus Thanks it's from copying the code, but it's not the reason for the problem otherwise I would've seen it in the js console.

Comment: After the return of your html from the ajax call you have to bind again the actions to the buttons or regenerate the DOM.

Comment: @iubema I sorry to say I don't know how to do that can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

JS generated DOM elements are not triggered by your code anymore. You have to create a document-event so your JS generated DOM elements will run properly.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

** Edit **

Maybe I'll give you a little example, how I meant to write your code. The problem you got is, that if you create an element with JS/jQ, your DOM has already been parsed with your javascript/jquery code and it doesn't recognize your newly created DOM.

This works fine:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '#st_score_form', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Button click");
    });

    $('body').append('<button id="st_score_form">Testbtn</button>');
});
</script>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    No content
</body>
</html>
```

This does **not** work

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#st_score_form').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Button click");
    });

    $('body').append('<button id="st_score_form">Testbtn</button>');
});
</script>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    No content
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: should my code look something like this `$(document).on('event', '#st_score_form', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // this is where I'm testing if the button is working
        alert("Button click");
        console.log("Button click");
            
    });`

Comment: No. Replace `event` with the event you want to have triggered. `$(document).on('click', '#st_score_form', function(event) {});`

Comment: that is just what I did and nothing happens. Once again this is how I did it: `$(document).on('submit', '#st_score_form', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // this is where I'm testing if the button is working
        alert("Button click");
        console.log("Button click");
            
    });` **Note here** I'm trying to trigger the on submit event of the form.

Comment: Updated. See post answer.

Comment: I did a test on what you suggested and it work. But in my case I want to trigger the on submit event of the form. Can I replace this line with details of the form that is being submitted? `$('body').append('<form id="st_score_form">Form fields goes here</form>');` You can take a look at my post for more clarification on this.